# Getting the following error “Error populating transaction after 10 anaconda retries…” in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, software-installation, installer-anaconda

I have downloaded CentOS 7 and trying to install it on my desktop and getting this error while installation.

> The following error occurred while installing. This is fatal error and installation will be aborted.
>
> Error population transcation after 10 anaconda retries: failure: Packages/ libreswam-3.23-3.el7.x86_64.rpm from anaconda: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Kindly help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like it is having issues with the CentOS mirrors. Try again and if it still is happening, try without networking.